# Update item quantity using custom dialog in Google Apps Script

Tags: forms, dialog, return, typeerror

I'm writing a script to take a user-given item number and quantity, find the current quantity for that item in a list, then add or subtract the user-entered quantity into the cell for that item.

I've previously gotten this to work using a simple dialog box that only takes the item number, then programmatically adds one to the cell. But now I need it to accept the quantity from the user.

I've now moved from the simple ui.prompt to a custom HTML widget. The code is failing at the point of returning the values for calculation. The dialog box appears OK, accepts input, and I can click 'OK'.

**
Failure line: var item = barcode[0];
Failure code: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

As this is for work, I unfortunately can't link to the actual spreadsheet.

[image: Example of the spreadsheet with target cell circled]

**Code.gs**

```
    //@OnlyCurrentDoc

    function onOpen() {
      let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.createMenu('Inventory')
      .addItem('Add inventory', 'addInventoryItem')
      .addItem('Subtract Inventory','subtractInventoryItem')
      .addToUi();
    }

    /////////////////// addInventoryItem ///////////////////
    //  
    //  Purpose: Gets item # and quantity from user
    //    calls function to get current qty of item
    //    adds qty entered by user and updates cell for item qty
    //    Loops, waiting for next item #
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function addInventoryItem() {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var i = 0;
      var item = -1;
      while(item !=1){
        var barcode = getBarcode();
        var item = barcode[0];
        var qty = barcode[1]
        logTimeRightNow();
        Logger.log("item: ");
        Logger.log(item);  
        Logger.log("Quantity: ");
        Logger.log(qty);
        if(item == 1){
          break
        }
        var currentVal = findBarcodeValue(item); // Get current value of column G and item row
        Logger.log("currentVal:");
        Logger.log(currentVal);
        var newVal = currentVal[0] + qty;
        Logger.log("newVal: ");
        Logger.log(newVal)
        sh.getRange(currentVal[1],7).setValue(newVal); // Set new value of column G on row # from findBarcodeValue
        Logger.log("Updated Value: ");
        Logger.log(findBarcodeValue(item)[0])
      }
    }
    
    
    /////////////////// findBarcodeValue ////////////////////
    //  
    //  Purpose: VLOOKUP Emulation.
    //    Input: item # (via barcode)
    //    Output: [current qty, line number]
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function findBarcodeValue(barcode) {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var data = sh.getRange('A1:G169').getValues();// create an array of data from columns A through G
      for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
        if (data[nn][0]==barcode){break} ;// if a match in column A is found, break the loop
          }
    // Browser.msgBox(data[nn][0]);// show column A
    return [data[nn][7], (nn + 1)] // Return column G value and row #
    }
    
    
    /////////////////// getBarcode //////////////////////////
    //  
    //  Purpose:  Calls custom dialog to get item # and 
    //    quantity from user
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function getBarcode() {
      var widget = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Inventory.html");
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(widget, "Item & Quantity");
    }
    
    
    /////////////////// returnItemAndQty ////////////////////
    //  
    //  Purpose:  Collects data from custom dialog and passes it
    //    back to original function (addInventoryItem)
    //
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    function returnItemAndQty(invForm) {
      return [invForm.item,invForm.qty]
    }
```

**Inventory.html**

```
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <script>
          function enterForm() { 
            google.script.run.returnItemAndQty(document.getElementById("invForm"));
            document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
            google.script.host.close();
          }
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <div id="form">
            <h1>Item & Qty</h1>
            <form id="invForm">
              <label for="item">Item</label>
              <input type="text" id="item" name="item"><br><br>
    
              <label for="qty">Quantity</label>
              <input type="qty" id="qty" name="qty"><br><br>
              <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="enterForm();">
            </form> 
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```